# How to properly allocate a dynamic one-dimensional array as a member of a class?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Here is my class so far:

```
template <typename T>
class myClass
{
private:
    size_t capacity_;
    size_t size_;
    T* the_array;
public:
    myClass(size_t cap) {
        capacity_ = cap;
        size_ = 0;
        the_array = new T[capacity_];
    }
    ~myClass() { clear(); }

    virtual size_t capacity() const {
        return capacity_;
    }

    virtual size_t size() const {
        return size_;
    }

    virtual bool clear() {
        delete[] the_array;
        return true;
    }   
};
```

I am trying to allocate the array in the constructor, but when I create a myClass object, its the_array is not an array with the capacity that I request. While debugging, the_array is only a pointer to T. I'm not sure whether the issue is in the constructor or in my declaration of the private variable for the pointer to the_array.

Comment: You can use std::vector if you want to save the headache

Comment: As an aside, you have `virtual` member functions but not a `virtual` destructor, which is usually a bad way to go. I'd suggest removing `virtual` here, or mark the destructor as `virtual` if you really do need dynamic dispatch.

Comment: You don't have a method for getting a new array if someone other than the destructor calls `clear`. This will leave the object in a bad state, so rethink `delete`ing the array in `clear` or allowing `clear` to be `public`.

Comment: [Handy extra reading](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). TL;DR version, if you have a destructor, you probably need a copy constructor and assignment operator to go along with it.

Comment: @user4581301 that makes sense. Moving clear() to private will solve this?

Comment: Solve your current problem, no. It will solve a future problem, though. Fun thing about pointers that may answer part of your question: They know what they point at, but they don't know how many, so there is no way for you to know after the fact if they are the size you asked for or not. Fortunately if `new[]` can't give you the number of elements you asked for, an exception will be thrown.

Comment: "the_array is only a pointer to T" -- I'm going to let you in on a big secret: there is no such thing as an array in C++. It's a mirage, an illusion, a sleight of hand. An array is really just a pointer to the first value of the array. Your debugger is simply showing you the real, red-pilled state of affairs. The only thing that's wrong with the shown code is that `clear()` should clear deleted array's pointer to a `nullptr`, and the class needs a copy constructor and an assignment operator.

Comment: Good on you to use a debugger. A lot of folk learning C++ don't and spend way longer learning than they had to.

Comment: You should add your code that uses `myClass` so we can tell if you do have a bug or just a conceptual problem with pointers we can easily explain (or point you at an existing Q&A that answers it).

Comment: @Ectofuctus C programmers use pointers, in 2021 C++ programmers uses smart pointers, now you can use smart pointers of QT, smart pointers of boost, smart pointers of standard library, but using raw pointers is like reinvent the wheel or just writing C instead of C++, smart pointers are the actual [modern]C++, using new and delete isn't a good method now. as @Tony Tannous mentioned, you can use `std::vector`.

Comment: Look up "C++ rule of three".   The gist is that, if your class directly manages a resource (memory in your case) that requires non-trivial destruction (i.e. releasing the resource) then your class also needs a copy constructor and an assignment operator.    In C++11 and later, the rule of three (often) becomes the rule of five.

Comment: Rule of 5 definitely fits this case. It is much easier to move the pointer to the data out of a soon-to-be disposed of `myClass` instance than it is to copy the sucker.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik um, that's wrong. Arrays do have a lot of quirks like not being assignable and converting to pointers if you sneeze at them, but they're very much their own kind of objects nonetheless.

Answer (score 2):

> when I create a myClass object, its the_array is not an array with the capacity that I request.

Yes, it is. Well, a pointer to such an array, anyway.

> While debugging, the_array is only a pointer to T.

It is a pointer to (the 1st element of) a dynamically allocated array holding elements of type `T`.

> I'm not sure whether the issue is in the constructor or in my declaration of the private variable for the pointer to the_array.

Neither. The issue is simply in your understanding of reality.

`new[]` allocates an array holding the specified number of elements of the specified type, and then returns a pointer to that memory. The debugger, on the other hand, has no way of knowing what kind of memory a pointer is pointing at. All it knows is that the pointer is pointing at an instance of the dereferenced type, so by default it can display only the data of that single instance.  But you know the pointer is actually pointing at an array instead, so you need to explicitly tell the debugger that fact so it can then display the other elements in the array.  Most debuggers provide a command to let you specify how many array elements are present at the memory address being pointed at.

The code you have shown is creating the array correctly. The code is merely incomplete in how it *manages* the array afterwards, as it does not follow the [Rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).  It needs to implement (or disable) a copy constructor and a copy assignment operator. And for C++11 and later, it should implement a move constructor and a move assignment operator as well. For example:

```cpp
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>

template <typename T>
class myClass
{
private:
    size_t capacity_;
    size_t size_;
    T* array_;

public:
    myClass(size_t cap = 0) {
        capacity_ = cap;
        size_ = 0;
        array_ = new T[capacity_];
    }

    myClass(const myClass& src) {
        capacity_ = src.capacity_;
        size_ = src.size_;
        array_ = new T[capacity_];
        std::copy_n(src.array_, size_, array_);
    }

    myClass(myClass&& src) {
        capacity_ = std::exchange(src.capacity_, 0);
        size_ = std::exchange(src.size_, 0);
        array_ = std::exchange(src.array_, nullptr);
    }

    ~myClass() { clear(); }

    myClass& operator=(myClass rhs) {
        capacity_ = std::exchange(rhs.capacity_, 0);
        size_ = std::exchange(rhs.size_, 0);
        array_ = std::exchange(rhs.array_, nullptr);
        return *this;
    }

    size_t capacity() const {
        return capacity_;
    }

    size_t size() const {
        return size_;
    }

    void clear() {
        delete[] array_;
        array_ = nullptr;
        capacity_ = size_ = 0;
    }   
};
```

That being said, you should use `std::vector` instead of `new[]`, then all of this detail is taken care of automatically for you, since `std::vector` follows the Rule of 3/5/0, and the compiler-generated constructors and assignment operators in your class will suffice to manage the vector properly, eg:

```cpp
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
class myClass
{
private:
    std::vector<T> vec_;

public:
    myClass(size_t cap = 0) {
        vec_.reserve(cap);
    }

    size_t capacity() const {
        return vec_.capacity();
    }

    size_t size() const {
        return vec_.size();
    }

    void clear() {
        vec_.clear();
    }   
};
```

Comment: An aside: the `vector`-using version doesn't need to have the extra copy, move, and destruction logic because whoever wrote `vector` did all the work for you and your class will make use of it by default. Take-away from this is you should implement the copy-move-destroy logic as close to the resource that requires it as possible, often adding in an extra object that does nothing but copy-move-destroy, because A) it's easier without all of the stuff that got added on later and B) it allows the stuff that got added later to be simpler.